# Error al filtrar precio

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

Tengo que programar esta consulta que devuelva los ID de las joyas que cuestan menos de 150 y  ordenados descendentemente. No puedo usar  joya.precio ya que su valor es null. El precio de la joya esta dado por la suma de los precios de sus materiales

Cuando quiero filtrar el precio me da error

```
SELECT joya.id, SUM(material.precio) AS precio 
FROM material
INNER JOIN contiene ON material.id = contiene.id_material
INNER JOIN joya ON contiene.id_joya=joya.id 
GROUP BY joya.id 
WHERE material.precio<'150'
ORDER BY precio desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Se trata de un problema de orden en las sentencias, el `WHERE` debe ir antes que el `GROUP BY`, quedando así:

```
SELECT joya.id, SUM(material.precio) AS precio 
FROM material
INNER JOIN contiene ON material.id = contiene.id_material
INNER JOIN joya ON contiene.id_joya=joya.id 
WHERE material.precio<'150'
GROUP BY joya.id 
ORDER BY precio desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando tienes que aplicar un filtro sobre el resultado de una agregación, en este caso el `SUM()` se usa el `HAVING`  de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT joya.id, SUM(material.precio) AS precio 
       FROM material
       INNER JOIN contiene ON material.id = contiene.id_material
       INNER JOIN joya ON contiene.id_joya=joya.id 
       GROUP BY joya.id 
       HAVING SUM(material.precio) < 150
       ORDER BY precio desc
```